# How to implement/adjust input shape for TorchMetrics multi class problem

Tags: python, object-detection, multiclass-classification, pytorch-lightning

**Backgroud:**

I use PytorchLightning to train with FasterRCNN and MaskRCNN for object detection with 2 different classes (multi-class classification).

**Task:**

Now i want to implement metrics e.g Precision, Recall etc. from [TorchMetrics](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/references/modules.html#classification).

As predicted output i have for each image a dictionary:

- 'boxes': Tensor with shape (Num_boxes, 4 for box coordinations)
- 'labels': Tensor with shape (Num_boxes,) label could be 1 or 2
- 'scores': the confidence score for each box, Tensor with shape (Num_boxes,)

**Problem:**

However, the desired [input shape for TorchMetric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly4jL.png) is totally different than what i have as prediction result, the questions are:

1. I don't understand what the preds shape is for multi-class (N,) or for multi-class with logits (N,C) and
2. how can i convert my output into this shape?

I have a hunch that they may want the box prediction result, i should first filter my output by score threshold and by IoU threshold, like in this function from [mmdetection](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/blob/master/tools/analysis_tools/confusion_matrix.py#L95-L142), but after that i can get fp, tp etc. instead of a tensor of shape(N,) or (N,C).

I hope I have stated my problem in an understandable way, any help would be really appreciated!